# Why is the resurrection for all of Yisroel, but the Garden of Eidin is only for some?

Tags: resurrection-of-the-dead, ramban

It says in the first Mishneh of the chapter Chaeilik in Sanhedrin, "All of Yisroel have a portion in the world to come etc...", Which is referring to the world of the resurrection, as it says in the gemara later on daf 90, that "these are those who don't have a portion in the world to come... One who denies the resurrection of the dead from the Torah... Measure for measure", which proves that since he's punished measure for measure, then the "world to come" here is speaking of the resurrection

Anyways, why is it that all of the people of Yisroel have a portion, seemingly without (as many) conditions (besides for the few mentioned in the gemara there, but in general the Mishnah says "all"...), While in the garden of Eidin, the world of souls without bodies, there are many conditions to get in, with many different judgements, as it's known that Achair was only let in after other people prayed for him, and even after all of that, he was only let in to the lower level of the garden of Eidin, but "all of Yisroel have a portion in the world to come", without conditions and the same kind of judgement?

And especially if the world of the resurrection will be much greater than the world of souls, since the souls ascend 3 times each day, and some have been there for thousands of years, yet in the time of the resurrection, they will all come back down into physical bodies in order to get the revelation of the resurrection of the dead, but why is that, if it will be for everyone without conditions?

And even more, the entire point of the ascents of the garden of Eidin involve forgetting ones previous level through the "river of fire", as it is known, which the souls pass through but only when they first enter from this world, but at every ascent to a higher level, they first most immerse in the river, in order to completely forget the previous level and become more refined and removed etc to rise to higher and higher levels, but at the time of the resurrection, they will all come *back* into physical bodies in order to recieve the revelations of the resurrection

So why (according to the Ramban) will the souls, who have been ascending to higher and higher levels etc., need to come back into physical bodies in order to recieve the revelations of the resurrection, and why is the resurrection for all of Yisroel, while the garden of Eidin is only for some, if the revelations of the resurrection are much greater than the garden of Eidin?

Comment: According to the Rambam "World to Come" refers to the afterlife,not the resurrection. And while all "Yisrael" have a portion toward it, he then lists qualifications for which Jews are Yisrael in good standing and included in this. Which is how the 13 articles of faith come in.

Comment: @micha cool story, the question is asking according to the Ramban as it says in the last paragraph

Comment: @MichaBerger Are you unfamiliar with the explicit teaching of the Lubavitcher Rebbe concerning this specific question contained in the Chassidic discourse beginning with the words, “להבין ענין תחיית המתים כו׳” found in the 3rd volume of Sefer HaMa’amarim Hameluket?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I think it's safe to say yes.

Comment: @robev Micha is quite capable of speaking for himself. If he is true to his good form, my guess would be that he is reviewing the citation if he doesn’t know it already. If you haven’t learned it, you should check it out on Hebrewbooks.org

Comment: @YaacovDeane sorry didn't realize you were addressing MichaBerger. He happens to be more well read than most.

Comment: @robev Micha learned in my home many years ago. He’s a good guy who has tried hard to be a positive influence in the world. Only blessings for him and his family...

Comment: There is a dispute between the Rambam and Ramban. According to the Rambam, the resurrection life is finite, after which the person died again. The ultimate reward requires not being veiled from G-d by a body. Whereas...

Comment: The Ramabn says that the ultimate reward is the resurrection life. And there is no second death. Therefore, they also disagree about what the. "world to come" refers to. I was saying, because of this,you cannot ask how how the Ramban says something on the basis of something in the Rambam's Commentary on the Mishnah.

Comment: In particular they argue about whether Gann Eden or  the post resurrection life is indeed greater. Whichever is greater though, that is what "world to come" means.

Comment: @micha yes that would be true, the question is simply asking according to the Ramban's understanding of the Mishnah only, although even according to the Rambam, part of this question still applies, namely, what would be the advantage of the resurrection in the first place, if the souls have been ascending higher and higher, beyond the confinements of the body